# Не отображаются пункты меню в плагине Yoast SEO

Tags: wordpress

В меню плагина не отображаются почти все пункты, никак не пойму почему, на разных сайтах и в обучающих видео везде это меню есть. Неужели оно есть только в премиум версии? тогда получается все туториалы только по премиум версии?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Ниже привел картинки меню на моем сайте и из туториалов.

[image: Меню Yoast SEO на моем сайте]

[image: Меню из туториалов]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Настройки плагина внимательно смотри.

Comment: Еще раз прошелся по настройкам и действительно, нужно было нажать всего одну кнопку, чтобы появились расширенные настройки. Спасибо:)